# Error en codigo para hallar moda de un vector de tamaño n (C++)

Tags: array

he escrito una funcion con la cual se deberia hallar la moda de una serie de datos de un vector de tamaño n, pero me devuelve numeros incorrectos y no encuentro el error, pues ya intente poniendo printf a diferentes partes de la funcion para buscar el error, y en donde deberia retornar numeros como 2 o 3, me devuelve numeros muy grandes o -1, a continuacion especificare en que parte aparecen estos errores, el codigo de la funcion es el siguiente:

```
int *shell(int *v,int t){
int i,k,j,salto=t/2;
int z;
while(salto>0)
{
    for(i=salto+1;i<t;i++)
    {
        j=i-salto;
        while(j>=0)
        {
            k=j+salto;
            if(v[j]<v[k])
            j=0;
            else
            {
                z=v[j];
                v[j]=v[k];
                v[k]=z;
            }
            j=j-salto;
        }
    }
    salto=salto/2;
}
return v;}


int mayorVector(int *c,int t){
int max, x;
for (int i=0; i<t; i++)
{
    if(c[i]>max)
    {
        max = c[i];
        x = i;
    }
}
return x;}
```

//los parametros de entrada son un vector c con datos en desorden generados aleatoriamente y t es el tamaño del vector

```
int Moda(int *c, int t){
int* f=(int *) malloc (sizeof (int) * t);  //vector para ubicar las frecuencias de los datos
int* l=(int *) malloc (sizeof (int) * t);  //vector para los datos y saber a que frecuencia corresponden dependiendo de las posiciones del vector f
int i=0;
int j,k,u;
int n=0;
int acum=1;
int* v=(int *) malloc (sizeof (int) * t); 
v=shell(c,t); //vector con los mismos datos que el vector de entrada c, pero con estos ordenados por shell
while(i<t-1)
{
    j=i+1;
    k=v[i];
    while(j<t)
    {
        if(v[i]==v[j])
        {
            acum++;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            l[n]=k;
            f[n]=acum;
            n++;
            acum=1;
            i=j;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(j==t)
    {
        l[n]=k;
        f[n]=acum;
        n++;
        acum=1;
        i=j;
    }
}
u=mayorVector(f,n); //mayorVector devuelve la posicion del dato mayor de un vector, sin embargo me devuelve la poscicion -1 (1er error)
return l[u];  //aqui retorna el dato con la posicion u, que seria la moda, pero me devuelve exactamente: 201339147
```

}

Se que no es la solucion mas corta, pero es la que yo le di, ademas de que parte de esta funcion me ayudaria a solucionar otros problemas, ojala me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿De donde sale la función *shell*? Como mínimo tienes un *memory leak* ya que pides memoria para *v* y luego pierdes el puntero. Esa asignación parece muy problemática.

Comment: De hecho no haces *free* de ninguno de tus *malloc*.

Comment: Y como tampoco tenemos el código de *mayorVector*, tampoco sabemos si el error está allí. Mira como poner un [mcve].

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya añadi las funciones que faltaban.